# How to repeat javascript click function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

long time reader first time poster. 
I'm totally new to this..
How do I make "ele.click();" to repeat more then once, so instead of it firing once, it will fire say 5 times in a row with a single "Z" press.. like Z Z Z Z Z.
Thank you in advance

```
(function(tags) {
    tags = ["INPUT", "SELECT", "TEXTAREA"];
    addEventListener("keydown", function(ev, ele) {
        if (ev.shiftKey || ev.ctrlKey || ev.altKey || tags.includes(ev.target.tagName)) return;
        switch (ev.key.toUpperCase()) {
            case "Z": // test
                if (ele = document.querySelector(".CLASS")) ele.click();
                break;
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont see the real utility of it, but i see this way:

Call the click passing the number of calls you want as param, like: "ele.click(5);"

Then, in your function you do something like:

```
nameFunction(times) {
    let done = 0;
    while(times > done) {
        done++;
        // do your logic
    }
}
```